# AJAX and Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, asp-classic, peoplesoft

NO JQUERY.  I am using peoplecode which is similar to JSP, ASP, and ZXZ.  The ajax request is triggered am I am trying to pull the text 'Hello World' from this script...

```
Function IScript_AJAX_Test()  
   %Response.Write("<div id='hello'>Hello World</div>");  
End-Function;
```

My javascript function that makes the ajax call looks like this...

```
function AJAX_test (ajax_link) {

  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == 'undefined') {
            XMLHttpRequest = function() {
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }     catch(e) {}
                try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }  catch(e) {}

            throw new Error('This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest or XMLHTTP.');
            };
        }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {

      document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = request.responseText.document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML;
      //document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = 'Testing';
    }  
  }
  request.open('GET', ajax_link, true);
  request.send(); 

  //document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = ajax_link;
}
```

As you can see in this line..

```
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = request.responseText.document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML;
```

...I am trying to grab the text by getting the innerHTML from the id.  This isn't working though.  When I click the button nothing happens.

I tried using the line below, but it returns an entire new page where the id would be (probably because of Peoplesoft)...

```
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

Can someone help me achieve this...

Comment: If you know what the response contains you could use a regular expression to pick the information you need from the responseText. So the question is: do you know what your are looking for and in what? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works for me, with

```
Function IScript_AJAX_Test()  
   %Response.Write("<div id='hello'>Hello World");  
End-Function;
```

and in the javascript

```
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

Make sure you call the content servlet (psc), not the portal servlet (psp), e.g. 
'http://peoplesofturl/**psc**/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/s/WEBLIB_Z_SYS.FUNCLIB.FieldFormula.IScript_AJAX_Test', otherwise you'll get the response wrapped in the peoplesoft portal.

You can generate the url from peoplecode with the [GenerateScriptContentRelURL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tpcl/book.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm#37ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__3d6f) or [GenerateScriptContentURL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tpcl/book.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm#37ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__3d6e) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple:

```
Function IScript_AJAX_Test()  
   %Response.Write("Hello World");  
End-Function;
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

Comment: Your response isn't a valid document element, it's just a string. So you can't handle it as if it is a real div. The browser will see it as a string only.

Comment: I tried that originally, but it is returning an entire new page where the id should be...I believe this is because of PEoplesoft.

Comment: You have to make sure that 'ajax_link' page is outputing only your response.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax might be two types. One is server-side and the other one is client-side. You are trying to get data from client side. In this case ajax fetch nothing but the whole page result of a page not a portion. You will have the whole page result(HTML output) if you write

```
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

But you cannot fetch just only the innerHtml part of certain portion of another page. On that case you will get the whole page.

Comment: Then how do I get the Hello World part only?

Comment: It is possible in server-side if you are fetching data from database but not in client side. At most you can do take page that only has the body or the html result "Hello world". Then you can fetch